# Jboss 7 Web service threads stuck at getRGB(...)

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, itext

I have a web service that converts an image to PDF using itext and then saves the document in the Database.

90% of the days it goes ok, but some days the conversion from of the image to document just takes too much time, and after a while some of them they aren't even finished.

This doesn't happen on peak time, or when are simulatineous request being processed. When it happens, it happens since the begining of the day and happens with every single one. It seems random (I know it isn't), but when the server is restarted: 
 - Sometimes it's ok, and all of the images take less than 1 second to finish
 - Sometimes it goes wrong since the first one, and some of them takes more than 20 MINUTES

The method is this:

```
private PdfPTable constroiPDF(BufferedImage image){

    PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(1);
    PdfPCell cell = null;
    // IMAGE        
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("",arialBd9));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    cell.setPaddingTop(ConstantesExpediente.padding20f);
    try {
        Image img = Image.getInstance(image, null);
        img.scaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4.width()-100, PageSize.A4.height()-100);
        img.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
        cell = new PdfPCell(img);
        cell.setBorderWidth(0); 
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(cell);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    table.setTotalWidth(PageSize.A4.width()-100)

    return table;
```

When I look to the memory dumps taken when this happens that are lots and lots of threads in this state:

```
  "http-executor-threads - 100" prio=5 tid=500 RUNNABLE
at java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.getRGBComponent(ComponentColorModel.java:893)
at java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.getGreen(ComponentColorModel.java:979)
at java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.getRGB(ComponentColorModel.java:1130)
   Local Variable: byte[]#15275
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:888)  
at sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource.sendPixels(OffScreenImageSource.java:175)
   Local Variable: sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster#46
   Local Variable: int[]#46200
at sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource.produce(OffScreenImageSource.java:187)
at sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource.addConsumer(OffScreenImageSource.java:66)
at sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource.startProduction(OffScreenImageSource.java:80)
   Local Variable: sun.awt.image.OffScreenImageSource#34
at java.awt.image.PixelGrabber.grabPixels(PixelGrabber.java:259)
at java.awt.image.PixelGrabber.grabPixels(PixelGrabber.java:226)
at com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:535)
   Local Variable: java.awt.image.PixelGrabber#34
at com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:694)
at pk.integrations.UploadImagesHelper.constroiPDF(UploadImagesHelper.java:245)
   Local Variable: java.util.GregorianCalendar#897
   Local Variable: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell#75
   Local Variable: java.lang.Long#649
   Local Variable: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable#34
at pk.integrations.UploadImagesHelper.upload(UploadImagesHelper.java:116)
   Local Variable: java.awt.image.BufferedImage#45
   Local Variable: java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream#387
   Local Variable: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter#44
   Local Variable: com.lowagie.text.Document#44
   Local Variable: java.util.ArrayList#392408
   Local Variable: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream#49
   Local Variable: java.util.zip.ZipInputStream#44
   Local Variable: byte[]#21031
   Local Variable: java.util.zip.ZipEntry#44
at pk.integrations.UploadImagesWS.upload(UploadImagesWS.java:25)
   Local Variable: pk.integrations.uploadimages.UploadImagesTO#32
   Local Variable: pk.integrations.uploadimages.UploadImagesHelper#44
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5252.invoke(<unknown string>)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.java:108)
   Local Variable: java.lang.reflect.Method#97547
   Local Variable: java.lang.reflect.Method#97548
   Local Variable: java.lang.Object[]#714045
at org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServiceEndpointInvoker.invoke(ServiceEndpointInvoker.java:183)
   Local Variable: org.jboss.ws.core.server.DelegatingInvocation#33
   Local Variable: org.jboss.ws.core.DirectionHolder#33
   Local Variable: org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.j2ee.serviceref.UnifiedHandlerMetaData$HandlerType[]#66
   Local Variable: org.jboss.ws.core.EndpointInvocation#33
   Local Variable: org.jboss.wsf.spi.metadata.j2ee.serviceref.UnifiedHandlerMetaData$HandlerType[]#67
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:352)
   Local Variable: javax.xml.soap.MimeHeaders#44
   Local Variable: org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPMessageImpl#44
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:248)
   Local Variable: org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServletHeaderSource#44
   Local Variable: org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.handler.SOAPMessageContextJAXRPC#44
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:183)
   Local Variable: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream#85
   Local Variable: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream#76
   Local Variable: org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServletRequestContext#43
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:108)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.AbstractEndpointServlet.service(AbstractEndpointServlet.java:87)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet.service(EndpointServlet.java:98)
at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
   Local Variable: org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade#91
   Local Variable: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade#90
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
   Local Variable: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain#170
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
   Local Variable: org.jboss.security.plugins.JBossSecurityContext#104
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:389)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
   Local Variable: org.apache.coyote.Request#90
   Local Variable: org.apache.coyote.Response#91
   Local Variable: org.apache.catalina.connector.Response#91
   Local Variable: org.apache.catalina.connector.Request#91
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
   Local Variable: org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo#74
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
   Local Variable: org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor#77
   Local Variable: java.net.Socket#363
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:508)
at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:806)
at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:847)
   Local Variable: org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor#146
   Local Variable: org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker#201
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

"http-executor-threads - 65" prio=5 tid=412 RUNNABLE
at java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.extractComponent(ComponentColorModel.java:794)
at java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.getRGBComponent(ComponentColorModel.java:897)
at java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.getGreen(ComponentColorModel.java:979)
at java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.getRGB(ComponentColorModel.java:1130)
   Local Variable: byte[]#15277
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:888)
...

 "http-executor-threads - 72" prio=5 tid=436 RUNNABLE
at java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.getAlpha(ComponentColorModel.java:1045)
at java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.getRGB(ComponentColorModel.java:1130)
   Local Variable: byte[]#15276
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:888)
```

Why are so many threads here? What represent this getRGB method? How can I solve the problem?

Some info:
Server: Jboss AS 7.2 (and it worked before the migration from Jboss 4)
JDK: 1.7
Average of images processed: 2000 per day
Itext version: 1.4

Thanks

Comment: The iText version you're using is from 2006. It's 7 to 8 years old. Have you tried upgrading? Could you provide the entire trace? Your trace cuts off at the getRGB() method, but from where is this method being called? Is it possible to provide the images that Java/iText chokes on?

Comment: Thanks Michael. I edited the post. The other stacktraces are exactly the same. The images I'm afraid I don't have acces to them. They are send directly from the client for the web service and i don't have access to them.

Comment: I've found that code in the 1.4 version and it hasn't changed since. Without more information on the images there's not much I can do. iText just calls the grabPixels() method and java.awt takes over and fails. Do you know the type of the images? Would you be open to preprocess the images (using JAI or Apache Commons Imaging)? I've found that those two either fix (or catch) image issues and throw more informative exceptions.

Comment: The image are JPEGs. Yes, I can preprocess the images. Thanks again Michael. 
But are you saying that it may be a problem of the images? I descarted that because it's either slow on ALL the images of the day (no exceptions during 24hours) or it works fine on ALL of them (again, no exceptions). but it starts failing in the very first image of the day, just after the server reboots.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is happening, but it seems to me it's failing on the Java part of this iText-Java interaction, but without seeing the images or being able to tinker with your machine I can only guess. And going from that trace, I suspect either the images or Java. Have you tried preprocessing them with JAI? Have you tried eliminating certain sources, like have you tried changing the server's Java version? Updated iText version? etc.

Comment: The last effort was to update Java to the latest version. No sucess.
Now, I'am trying to reimplement the method trying to avoid passing on grabPixels(). 
If it still doesn't work, the next step will maybe update iText.
Thanks again Michael.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this issue?  We've been seeing something similar with JBoss 7.1.1.

Comment: I was never able to solve this problem. I had to reimplement my method replacing:
"Image img = Image.getInstance(image, null);"
by:
"Image img = Image.getInstance(image);"
to avoid the code passing in the place it was stuck.

Hope it helps nate